# Laravel Validation: Second rule does not run

Tags: php, laravel, validation, error-handling, laravel-validation

I have this validation in my controller:

```
  $rules = [
    'participants' => 'required|atleast_one'
  ];
  
  Validator::extendImplicit('atleast_one', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
      // Long conditions. 
      // Returns true or false
  });

  $error = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
```

The second rule `atleast_one` is a custom rule using the extend method.
I tested this rule **alone** and it works. But why is it when I put the two rules together (`'participants' => 'required|atleast_one'`), the second one doesn't work? I tried rearranging it and still the same, the second rule doesn't work. Did I miss something on the Laravel documentation?

Comment: what laravel version are you using

Comment: I am using Laravel Framework 5.5.44 @omaresmaeel

Comment: have you tried the array syntax something like this: `['required', 'atleast_one']`

Comment: Yes, I tried it. And the same thing happens.